# Stitching a moving object which is partially visible in view of stationary camera

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0, panoramas, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch a moving car, which is not completely visible horizontally, ( although completely visible vertically ) from camera view port.

Camera is stationary, 1-2 meters apart from the moving object ( similar to a gate setup ), taking side view of car. But since Camera is too close it can only capture a part of car.

I tried stitching multiple frames using this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/). But this only works when camera itself is rotated around axis or moved. Otherwise, because of background features it places frames onto each other since background is same in each frame ( see tutorial for reference ).

Basically what i'm trying to achieve is, given a video clip of moving car (such that complete car is never in one frame), build image of complete car by stitching the video frames.

Any algorithm, library or reference would be helpful.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you found a good solution to this in the end?